# Looping through a list - when index reaches end, start from 0

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops

I want to understand the logic of looping through a list. When I reach the end of list, I want the index to start from 0 again. The list is running in a loop and termination will happen, so it will not be an infinite loop.

I have seen solution using % operator but I don't understand it. Something like below but with % instead. I want to understand how that will work.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
   if(i == n - 1) { i = 0; }
}
```

Comment: That will become an infinite loop and will never stop

Comment: I have a termination logic in place. It will be in a for loop. How do you do that now?

Comment: `%` is the *modulo* operator. It takes two operands, `a % b`, which denotes what amount will remain if you divide *a* by *b*. E.g. 17 % 5 = 2, because you can subtract 5 from 17 for three times, and then 2 will be left over.

Comment: The thing is, if you do the same for the *size of the list*, the index will "wrap around" and will be always `0 <= n < listSize`.

Comment: if you need to make an infinite loop by reseting it and use a different "termination logic", maybe your loop is wrong and the logic should be changed

Comment: this whole question sounds like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please add more context, like the relation between your termination logic and the current loop condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) `%` is the remainder after a division.

> Given two positive numbers, a and n, a % n is the remainder of the Euclidean division of a by n, where a is the dividend and n is the divisor.

You said you have a list, if you use `% list.length()` this will give you values from 0 to list.length().

See the following code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("first");
list.add("second");
list.add("third");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("element: " + list.get(i % list.size()));
}
```

this outputs:

```
element: first
element: second
element: third
element: first
element: second
element: third
element: first
element: second
element: third
element: first
```

You can check it working [here](http://tpcg.io/DXtN9yMw).

Answer (score 1):

You can increment the counter by 1 and take the remainder of that divided by the size of the list. The `%` operator in Java takes the remainder after dividing by a number i.e., `a % b` returns the remainder when `a` is divided by `b`. Ergo, when the counter reaches the list's size, the remainder will be zero and it will be reset to 0; when the counter is less than the list's size, the remainder when divided by the size will be the counter itself.

```
for(int i = 0, size = list.size(); ; i = (i + 1) % size){
    //do something; add terminating condition
}
```

See also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// Will be an infinite loop 
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
   if(i == n - 1) { i = 0; }
}
```

`%` gives you the remainder of a division.

```
10%2 == 0  // 10/2 = 5
10%3 == 1  // 10/3 = 3 and remainder 1
```

With `%` you can do something like this:

```
// Will be an infinite loop 
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
   if(i == n - 1) { i = i%(n-1); }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain doing this with % operator and the logic behind it?

Answer (score 0):

```
package testproj;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("string1");list.add("string2");list.add("string3");
        int j=0; //loop braking.
        for (int i=0;i<=list.size();i++) {
            if (i == list.size()) {
                i=0;
            }
            //This will go infinite loop. need a way to break the loop.
            //Below is just demonstration.
            j++;
            if (j==10) break;

            System.out.println("Do something with " + list.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```